# SQLite BETWEEN dates error

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, between

I've got the following code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('wereldzaak.sqlite')
curs = conn.cursor()
x = curs.execute('''SELECT SUM(price)
                    FROM purchase, product
                    WHERE dt_iso BETWEEN ‘2015-01-01' AND ‘2015-12-31’ ''')
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

```
WHERE dt_iso BETWEEN ‘2015-01-01' AND ‘2015-12-31’ ''')
sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "' AND ‘2015-12-31’ "
```

I looked it up on the internet, but I still don't know what's wrong with my code

Comment: Those aren't valid apostrophes that you're putting around the date strings.

Comment: Date literals in SQLite don't take backticks, they take single quotes.  So use `BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is that character actually a backtick (or referred to as a backtick)? In my editor, backticks look very different

Comment: The two tables also need to use `JOIN` to connected

Comment: @roganjosh Well it isn't a single or double quote, so I don't think it would work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry, I wasn't suggesting it would work, I was just more curious about whether that character is actually referred to as "backtick" (I've seen it in a couple of questions and I don't know how to reference it) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems

- You used triple single-quote instead of triple double-quote (replace ''' with """). Triple single-quote are not supported in python
- the single quotes are not plain single quote (use '). You should fix your editor to be in a python compatible mode.